# TypeError: _nextProps.children is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-context

I'm trying to use react context with nextJS and i'm getting this error:

```
Server Error
TypeError: _nextProps.children is not a function
```

My _App.js:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Router from "next/router";
import { Provider } from "next-auth/client";
import DataContextProvider from "../data/data-context";
import Layout from "../components/layout/layout";
import "../styles/globals.css";


function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Provider session={pageProps.session}>
      <DataContextProvider>
        <Layout>
          <Head>
            <meta name="description" content="Uploader" />
            <meta
              name="viewport"
              content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"
            />
          </Head>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </DataContextProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

I searched everywhere but found no solution, thanks for answering

Comment: stackoverflow won't let me post context code it says you post is mostly code...but im sure the problem is in _App.js,That's the only place i used DataContextProvider...

Comment: `function MyApp({ component: Component, ...pageProps }) {...`

Comment: @meine it didn't work still getting the same error

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason you might get this error is because you try to render the context itself, instead of the context provider.

This fails with the error `TypeError: _nextProps.children is not a function` on the server side, or `TypeError: render is not a function` if it happens on the client side:

```js
import { createContext } from 'react';

const Context = createContext('');

function App() {
  return <Context value="" />
}
```

Rendering the provider instead will work:

```js
function App() {
  return <Context.Provider value="" />
}
```

---

In your specific example, you do

```js
import DataContextProvider from "../data/data-context";
```

And render

```js
<DataContextProvider>
  ...
</DataContextProvider>
```

Is is possible that what you call `DataContextProvider` is actually just a context? It is not possbile to tell without looking at the code inside `data/data-context`.

Answer (score 0):

Search in your project for props.children (caps insensitive)
You're probably assuming the component has children when it doesn't